# Ways to prove $P\implies Q$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Suppose $P\implies Q$ is to be proven, where $P$ and $Q$ are two statements. Can it be proven as follows:

We take the following together:

1. $P$
2. negation of $Q$

Then, we proceed with these two things. We reach at a state where we conclude that “negation of $Q$“ fails to hold. Or, we reach at a state where we conclude that $P$ fails to hold.  Then, can we say the proof is done?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. In the first case, "negation of $Q$ failing to hold" is equivalent to "$Q$ holding", so in that case you have proven that, under $P$, $Q$ always holds. In the second case, you have done the same, you have proven that $\neg Q\implies\neg P$, which is the same as $P\implies Q$.

Answer (score 3):

$$P\rightarrow Q\\\lnot P\lor Q\\\lnot P\lor \lnot(\lnot Q)$$
Since the three propositions above are tautologically equivalent to one another (easily verifiable using their truth tables), proving the statement $P\implies Q$ is indeed equivalent to proving that

- either $P$ fails to hold
- or the negation of $Q$ fails to hold.

Answer (score 3):

In a Natural Deduction system for Classical Logic, the derivation of **a contradiction** under the assumptions of $P$ and $\lnot Q$ will suffice to deduce $P\to Q$.

$$\def\fitch#1#2{~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline #2\end{array}}\def\nfitch#1{\begin{array}{|l}#1\end{array}}\nfitch{~~\vdots\\~\fitch{~~h.~P}{\fitch{~~i.~\lnot Q}{~~~\vdots\\~~j.~\bot\hspace{11ex}\text{somehow}}\\~~k.~\lnot\lnot Q\hspace{10ex}\lnot\mathsf I~i{-}j\\~~\ell.~Q\hspace{13ex}\lnot\lnot\mathsf E~k}\\~~m.~P\to Q\hspace{9ex}{\to}\mathsf I~{h{-}\ell}}$$

Note: *Any* valid contradiction will do, whether it is a contradiction of either assumption, or something else.